# Out of 2 jvm argument (-D) only one is accessible from class but not the other one

Tags: java, jvm, arguments, cucumber

So I have a gradle project based on cucumber framework and I have a step in stepdefinition file which is like below(rough code) :

```
@Given
public void generateTextFile() {
    String pass = System.getProperty("pass");
    String fileName = System.getProperty("fileName");
    Sout(pass) ;
    Sout(filename) ;
}
```

I am running this program from command line as below:

```
gradle :proj:cucumber -Ptags=@customTest -Dpass=abcd -DfileName=file.txt
```

Now the output of this code is

```
null
file.txt
```

The problem that I am facing is that out of two jvm arguments my code is reading the fileName argument but null is being printed for pass argument.

Can someone please help on why is Java showing such behavior or if something is wrong with my core?

Comment: Quick update - When I pass the same jvm options from Idea run configuration, it works fine. But same doesn't work when I pass it from command prompt as mentioned in main question.

Comment: Check your gradle config. Gradle starts a new JVM and doesn't pass properties along unless you do that explicitly.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje thanks for pointing that out. I was able to resolve the issue by reading -D properties first in build.gradle file and then passing it through command line.